# Is there a way to add some js into all pages after loading via selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver

I am working on creating automated test using selenium. Currently i want execute some js code in every page/frame after it is loaded in order to have ability to call some testing functions in js. It is not nessecary to execute it immediatly after page loaded, I just want to be shure it will executed on every page.

To solve this problem I wrote my own implementator of WebDriver which, using delegate pattern, add js executing after method "get" is called. The same way I add script executing in all method of driver.switchTo() object that changes current frame.

The problem is in case when page reloads after clicking on some links/executing some js code. It is easy to undestand that in such case my script wouldn't be executed.

Is there a way to cover this behaviour using selenium WebDriver?

Any ideas or hacks are greating.

Answer (score 1):

You can have fiddler run in the background to proxy all HTTP methods..... At fiddler you can add a custom rule to alter response from server (by inserting JS ) for every specific type of HTTP call GET /POST (exclud PNG/IMG etc.)... I do this all time..to replicate hard to test scenarios.

Comment: Can you please provide more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this server-side : Extends all your servlets with a generic servlet that prepend your js code only when Selenium is running(set a static variable on server when selenium is starting)

Comment: O_o we are talking about selenium WebDriver which launched separately from application.

Comment: When starting selenium, you can call a special url to the server that trigger the "test" mode.

Comment: definetly it is possible, but not the case, as I am not allowed to alter server while creating tests :(.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using `WebSocket`. Create a WebSocket server in the application. After the initial `get`, `execute_script` that opens a connection to the server. When the browser moves to a new page, the socket connection is closed - you can execute_script again. The whole thing is a bit more complicated because you need to check for any `iframe`s, retrying the connection if it fails etc.

I was able to make this work well with Firefox, Chrome. Should work with Edge/IE also.